# Font looks terrible in chromium based Brave Browse - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: fonts, chromium

I just switched from windows 10 to Ubuntu. I know a lot of things are changed but fonts does not seems right to me.

Installed Brave Browser (chrome is same), The web fonts are blurry and does not feel good in the eyes. Tweaked some settings but didn't helped. Bold text is more problematic.

This is not specific to brave browser as Firefox is rendering almost same. I know some sites like twitter.com use system default font but i think this is not website specific.

Screenshot of Google.com Look at the text and the browser tabs title.
[Screenshot of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CVye.png)

Comment: You can change font type and font quality by installing gnome-tweaks. You can also change the font type in your browser settings.

Comment: I do not have such an issue on 18.04 ... did you jack about with your graphics drivers or are you using the default nouveau driver ?